# Чтение CSV файла в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

В [csv-файле](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3kDb/5BwZkTWKb) содержатся целые и дробные числа, например: 18,6 и 15. Однако, при отображении выборки после запятой у всех чисел ноль.

Подскажите как исправить.

Код:

```
import csv

Sample=[]
with open("sample2.csv", encoding="ANSI") as V:
    SR=csv.reader(V)
    for row in SR:
        Sample.append(float(row[0]))
print(sorted(Sample))
```

Comment: csv.reader(V, delimiter=';')

Comment: это не два числа 18 и 6, а одно дробное 18,6

Comment: если добавить разделитель то появляется ошибка - ValueError: could not convert string to float: '21,5'

Comment: в `sample2.csv` файле замените запятые `18,6`  на точку `18.6`

Comment: `Sample.append(float(row[0].replace(",", "."))`

Comment: Вы для каких целей читаете csv? может, вам больше подойдет другой метод чтения?

Comment: Для анализа выборки